# Can't install CYGWIN as windows service

Tags: service, cygwin

I've installed CYGWIN on my windows server,

And now I'm trying to run it as a service so it will be running on every system startup,  This is the command I tried but I get the error:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin>C:\cygwin64\bin\cygrunsrv.exe -I CYGWIN_SSHD -path C:\cygwin64\b
in\cygstart.exe
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv: Trailing commandline arguments not allowed
Try `/usr/bin/cygrunsrv --help' for more information.
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: cygstart is not a service, so it will not work anyway. Please clarify what is your expectation.

Comment: I figured it out, To install Cygwin as a service I needed to run "ssh-host-config" and this will install it as a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, To install Cygwin as a service I needed to run "ssh-host-config" insert all the needed definitions and this will install it as a service called **"CYGWIN sshd".**